# Understanding relationship between T-Score and percentile

Tags: t-test, quantiles

Suppose I am told that a person's raw score on a certain test was 26, the T-Score is 45, and the percentile is 31. From what I know about T-Scores, I'm having trouble understanding whether such numbers are even possible (in normally distributed data).

My understanding is that, for the T-Score, 50 means the raw score is just about average (at the very top of the bell curve), and each 10 points away from 50 represents one standard deviation. So, in the case of a T-Score of 45, my understanding it that the person's raw score was one half of a standard deviation from the mean. And, because one standard deviation encompasses about 34 points below or above the mean, half a standard deviation encompasses about 17 points below or above the mean.

So this person's T-Score of 45 means that the person is in the middle 34% of the population. But then I don't understand how their percentile could be 31, because that would mean they are **not** in the middle 34% of the population.

So it seems that either the data is not normally distributed, or that I am not understanding something fundamental about the relationship between raw score, T-Score, and percentile. Given those alternatives, my money is on the latter.

Comment: Maybe you should give a formula to show what you mean by T score.

Comment: Well, that's the problem I guess. I only have a printed report that says the "T-Score" is 45 and the "percentile" is 31. But in any case, I think I know the answer now. Each 10 points of T-Score represent one standard deviation from the mean. So in this case 45 means you're half a standard deviation from the mean, which means you are in the "average" ranges. Also my understanding is that the percentile is fixed once you know the T-Score. In this case T-Score is 45, and the corresponding percentile has to be 31. (Similarly if we were given the percentile we could computer the T-Score.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the test you are looking at is a psychometric test, which uses a different T-score than what you would get from a T-test. T-scores in psychometric testing is just a scaled z-score. The formula is **T = (Z x 10) + 50**, with Z being the z-score and T being the T-score.

Comment: +1 Your formula is consistent with a T-score of 45 corresponding to the 31st percentile, as well as the OP's "understanding that the person's raw score was one half of a standard deviation from the mean."